# Improve speed of scikit-learn multinomial logistic regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn

i am trying to train a logistic regression model in scikit learn and it is taking very long to train, around 2 hours. The size of the dataset is 21613 x 19. I am new to scikit learn, as such i dont know whether my code is wrong or that it just takes very long to train. Any suggestion on how to improve the training speed would be very much appreciated!

code used to train is below

```
# get the LogisticRegression estimator
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# training the model
# apply algorithm  to data using fit()
clf = LogisticRegression(solver='newton-cg',multi_class='multinomial')
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a specific reason for using this solver, one thing you can do is parallelize the computations by setting the `n_jobs=-1` argument.

If you're open to using other solvers, you can use faster solvers with a *one-versus-rest* strategy. For instance:

```
clf = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear', multi_class='ovr')
```

It's all in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html), which can help you guide your choice of solver:

#### solver : *{‘newton-cg’, ‘lbfgs’, ‘liblinear’, ‘sag’, ‘saga’}, default=’lbfgs’*

Algorithm to use in the optimization problem.

- For small datasets, ‘liblinear’ is a good choice, whereas ‘sag’ and
  ‘saga’ are faster for large ones.
- For multiclass problems, only ‘newton-cg’, ‘sag’, ‘saga’ and ‘lbfgs’
  handle multinomial loss; ‘liblinear’ is limited to one-versus-rest
  schemes.
- ‘newton-cg’, ‘lbfgs’, ‘sag’ and ‘saga’ handle L2 or no penalty
- ‘liblinear’ and ‘saga’ also handle L1 penalty
- ‘saga’ also supports ‘elasticnet’ penalty
- ‘liblinear’ does not support setting penalty='none'

Comment: thanks man,just to ask how long should training a small dataset of 21000 rows be?

Comment: I think very fast, multiplied by every label you have. Do you have many categories?

Comment: i tried training the model 15 mins ago and have not finished training

Comment: Isn't that your number of columns?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably that slow because of the solver you have chosen. The newton-cg is a newton method. It's slow for large datasets because it computes the second derivatives. Use a different solver like sag or saga, they are fast for big datasets.

Comment: alright thankyou., just to check, how fast should the training be done?

Comment: for you, it should take around 3 seconds,maximum. Just being curious, are you using kc_house_data dataset?

Comment: yes, it is that dataset. it still takes quite a while to train tho.

Comment: It's probably some other issue rather than your code, for it being slow. Because when I tried logistic regression on the same dataset with newton-cg solver, it took around 3 seconds to execute. And without providing any solver it took 2 seconds to give the output. Which IDE you're using?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to change your solver. The [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) says that scikit-learn has 5 different solvers: 'sag', 'saga', 'newton-cg', 'lbfgs', and 'liblinear' (not suitable for multinomial).

```
import time
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# Set training and validation sets
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000000, n_features=19, n_classes = 8, n_informative=8)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=1000)

# Solvers
solvers = ['newton-cg', 'sag', 'saga', 'lbfgs']

for sol in solvers: 
    start = time.time()
    logreg = LogisticRegression(solver=sol, multi_class='multinomial')
    logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
    end = time.time()
    print(sol + " Fit Time: ",end-start)
```

Output (from 16GB RAM 8 Core Macbook):
[image]

Choosing the right solver for a problem can save a lot of time (code adapted from [here](https://medium.com/distributed-computing-with-ray/how-to-speed-up-scikit-learn-model-training-aaf17e2d1e1)). To determine which solver is right for your problem, you can check out the table from the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression) to learn more (notice that 'newton-cg' is not faster for large datasets).

[image]